# Не могу написать extends ViewHolder в адаптере, не видит среда его

Tags: android, kotlin, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter, viewholder

Проблема: когда писал приложение на джаве, с библиотекой [CardStackView](https://github.com/yuyakaido/CardStackView), в адаптере строил `CardStackView.ViewHolder`. Сейчас делаю аналогичное на Kotlin (новый для меня язык), и почему-то не могу унаследоваться от `CardStackView.ViewHolder`, только `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` программа видит.
Где я что не углядел?

```
import com.yuyakaido.android.cardstackview.CardStackView;

public class LevelsAdapter extends ListAdapter<Word, LevelsAdapter.LevelsViewHolder> {

    protected LevelsAdapter(@NonNull DiffUtil.ItemCallback diffCallback) {
        super(diffCallback);
    }

    public class LevelsViewHolder extends CardStackView.ViewHolder {
    /// bla bla bla
```

А сейчас на котлине пишу и почему-то не могу вызвать `CardStackView.ViewHolder`:

```
import com.yuyakaido.android.cardstackview.CardStackView

class DrillerAdapter() : ListAdapter<Word,> {

    class DrillerViewHolder(private val binding: CardstackItemBinding) : CardStackView.//нет вьюхолдера 
в подсказках, если сам пишу то он красный (Unresolved reference: ViewHolder)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё верно. В отличии от Java, Kotlin позволяет использовать ***только*** прямые родительские классы для объявления и инициализации вложенных. Среда не может найти этот класс, из-за того что у `CardStackView` нет вложенного класса `ViewHolder`. В вашем случае необходимо использовать `RecyclerView.ViewHodler`